# Passing data using storyboardWithName will return NULL if not given enough time

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, parsing, storyboard

I'm trying to figure out why things happening the way they are described in the code. 
I can understand that if `aComb.someArray` isn't allocated yet in the time of the `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` it will return a NULL but the data will magically appear there if i'll set a timer. I'd love an explanation and an idea how to avoid this without using an ugly timer.

**ViewControllerA:**

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    ViewControllerB *aComb = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerBID"];
    aComb.view.frame = self.combinationsContainer.bounds;
    aComb.someArray = _someArray;
    [self.combinationsContainer addSubview:aComb.view];
    [self addChildViewController:aComb];
    [aComb didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

**ViewControllerB:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"%@",_someArray); //<-- this will return NULL
}
```

**ViewControllerB with timer:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1
                                                    target: self
                                                  selector: @selector(test)
                                                  userInfo: nil
                                                   repeats: NO];
}
-(void)test
{
         NSLog(@"%@",_someArray); // <-- this will return Data
}
```

Comment: There's stuff that happens between `didLoad` and `viewWillAppear`. Try moving your `NSLog` to `viewWillAppear` and see if it has the desired effect.

Comment: Or even `viewDidAppear`

Answer (score 0):

When you call `aComb.view.frame = self.combinationsContainer.bounds;` it triggers didLoad method of the ViewControllerB. But by the time your array is not assigned, hence it returns `Nil`.But when the timer fires array gets its value.

To fix this issue. Assign the array before setting frame. I mean,

```
aComb.someArray = _someArray;
aComb.view.frame = self.combinationsContainer.bounds;
```

Comment: Nop, I'm still getting NULL;

Comment: instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier is calling viewDidLoad somehow. You can use didAppear method to avoid timer. You can check that by keeping breakpoints in viewDidLoad and before instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier.